# How to stop the fragment to run in background?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which is used on the very first page of the app. After the user performs some operation on the fragment and intends to a new Activity to do another processing, my aim is that at this time the fragment should stop completely and later on if the user does an intent to the fragment then only it should start again from scratch.
How shall I avoid running it in the background and how to stop and start the fragment?

Comment: Your words are very confusing. fragment does not run  in background. Its all about Fragment BackStack . Read about `FragmentTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your requirement exactly, may be there are other best ways to achieve that.

But you can can call `onDestroyView()` in `onPause()` of your fragment. So whenever user leaves that fragment onDestroyView will always be called. And your view will be recreated when user comes back.